# rails 3.1 Whenever gem works in development but not in production. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, whenever, rails-3.1

Rails 3.1 + Whenever gem.
I've got 2 jobs scheduled in Whenever. However, apparently nothing happens.
I have tried these methods through Heroku console, and they work. So I reckon that they do not get fired at any point. Am I missing something?

config/schulde.rb

```
every 1.day, :at => '03:30' do
 runner "Alarm.proba"
end

every 1.day, :at=> '3:32 am' do
 runner "Alarm.proba2"
end
```

Alarm model

```
def self.proba
 @event = Event.find(10)
 @user =User.find(12)
 EventNotifier.alarm(@event, @user).deliver
end

def self.proba2
 @event = Event.find(10)
 @user =User.find(13)
 EventNotifier.alarm(@event, @user).deliver
end
```

$ crontab -l

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: quasi
5 4 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/sergioabendivar/railsProjects/Tutos/quasi && script/rails runner -e production '\''Alarm.proba'\'''

5 4 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/sergioabendivar/railsProjects/Tutos/quasi && script/rails runner -e production '\''Alarm.proba2'\'''
```

I assume that it woks in development because  my console now says "You have an email". Actually if I check the email I got quite a lot.

Comment: if running local you can enter enable sendmail in console wich handles the delivery. also make sure your smtp properties are set correctly.

Comment: It is in heroku. If a run Alarm.proba from heroku console I receive the email. It works fine.

Comment: Solution! Whenever gem deleted and Heroku Scheduler added.
http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/11/12/heroku_scheduler_add_on_now_available

Answer (score 2):

Use Heroku Scheduler instead: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler